# Track Individual Session tracking

Tags: tracking

In my website, I want to track my visitor who are searching for product after logged in. Can i get those list.

I read this [Is it possible to use Google Analytics to track single user account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030780/is-it-possible-to-use-google-analytics-to-track-single-user-account) But I can get login id of that user with detail what he/she searched for?

Comment: If they've "logged in", surely they have an ID? Just associate that with the session ID on the server side.

Comment: Yes In my site user need to be logged in through USERid to browse. Now I am looking for technique from which I can track individual user by search query performed on my website.

Comment: So track them with the USERid then!