# Create dimension with md5 function

Tags: hash, google-analytics

We’ve started to sent to GA hashed dimension our UNQ ID of each visitor. Therefore I can’t see previous **unhashed** data gathered before. Is there any way how to define to my dimension something like this?

1. check what input GA gathered
2. if it hashed, proceed
3. if it is not hashed, hash it with MD5
4. proceed

Is it possible to do it in GA GUI without using GA add-on and writing own script?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible within the Google Analytics UI. Also using md5 is probably a violation of Google's term of service, or at least they explictely state that [Google has a **minimum** hashing requirement of SHA256](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en).

In general you must not store data that identifies a visitor, so having PII displayed somewhere in the interface is not feasible within the terms of service (also this would be illegal in any countries).

Comment: Well, you are able to send UNQ ID of each visitor to GA according to Terms&Cond. Even though you **can't** send any sensitive data (= personal data) such as first, last name, address. You are able to generate your own unq id, hash it, pair it outside of GA. Thank you for your reply. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030780/is-it-possible-to-use-google-analytics-to-track-single-user-account

Comment: You cannot encrypt within the GA interface (which is what you asked), if you send an encrypted value you have to use at least SHA256 (as per Googles documentation).  Pairing hashed data with outside data is indeed possible (if you are in the EU a hashed that can be paired with external data will be considered PII starting in 2018 at which point it violates the TOS), but that does not seem relevant to your question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn’t clarify my answer below your answer. We will fix it. Even though it is not relevant, it is very interesting topic.